# NOT EXISTS in select query to get result

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I have a table with the below set up, what I’m trying to extract is a list of all accounts that have an HH1 but does not have a DIS within 5 days.

```
AccountNo   Code    Date
125487  HH1 17/11/2013
125487  DIS 18/11/2013
123368  HH1 16/11/2013
124587  HH1 10/09/2013
```

I’ve tried using a NOT EXISTS as per below but its just returns records within the last 5 days?

```
SELECT     mx.AccountNo
                , mx.Code
                , mx.Date
FROM         dbo.tblmtx AS mx INNER JOIN
                dbo.tblM AS m ON m.AccountNo = mx.AccountNo 
WHERE     (Code IN ('HH1')) AND (FA = 'R') AND
              (mx.Date > GETDATE()-5 ) 
           AND 
                NOT EXISTS 
            ( SELECT 1 FROM  dbo.tblMaTx AS mx2
                WHERE mx2.AccountNo = mx.AccountNo 
                     AND mx2.Date >= GETDATE()-5
                     AND mx2.Code = 'DIS'
                     AND mx2.FA = 'R'
                     )
                    GROUP BY mx.AccountNo
                , mx.Code
                , mx.Date
        ORDER BY mx.AccountNo
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: there is no `FA` column on your table. The first line on the `WHERE` statement the column `CODE` is ambiguous, should be either `mx.Code` or `m.Code`

Answer (score 0):

To get the accounts that do have a DIS in the last five days

```
select accountNo from accounts where acc.code = 'DIS' and  acc.date > GETDATE()-5
```

To get the account that DO have

```
select accountNo from accounts where acc.code = 'HH1'
```

Then:

```
 select accountNo from accounts where acc.code = 'HH1' and accounts.accountNo not in 
   (select accountNo from accounts acc2 where acc2.code = 'DIS' and  
               acc2.date > GETDATE()-5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT a.AccountNo, a.Code, a.[Date]
FROM [YourTable] a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [YourTable] a2
        ON a.AccountNo = a2.AccountNo
        AND a2.[Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -5, a.[Date]) AND a.[Date]
WHERE a.Code = 'HH1'
    AND a2.AccountNo IS NULL
```